# Is my Web Apps account under threat or am I being paranoid?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, security

I've just checked my IP addresses on Web Apps (Link for Web Apps mods and developers):

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/admin/show-user-ips/21

and a couple show up as being used once but the weird thing is they resolve to South Africa - somewhere I've never been.

Is this someone trying to hack my account or just an artefact of the way the internet routes data. There's no data information on when these IPs were first and/or last used so I don't know whether this is a recent thing or not.

The dns lookups resolve to Durban and Johannesburg and the names end in "dsl.mweb.co.za" implying (I think) that they are end user addresses.

The IP cross reference table shows some interesting things also:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/admin/xref-user-ips/21

Other users, who live in completely different continents appear to share the same IP addresses as me when I know that I have a static IP at home and I assume the company where I work does too.

Comment: Be honest; what'd you do to Diago?

Comment: Does the IP cross-reference show anything? (A tool I admittedly normally ignore for mods, since in my case it shows that I have 7 sockpuppets, including Community and another mod)

Comment: @Michael - the cross reference - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/admin/xref-user-ips/21 shows that some users are using MY ip address (which I find harder to believe).

Comment: Huh, thought I'd check my own on SU, should I worry that I've apparently used `127.0.0.1` over 500 times...?

Comment: @DMA It says that for everyone. I've never heard of it picking some random address in South Africa though (although it's probably the same kind of thing; I doubt very much it's actually somebody logging into the account from that address)

Comment: @Michael that's OK then, I'd assumed that was probably the case as I've seen it on other people's lists as well, so I'd not bothered to raised it before. This just seemed like a good opportunity to do so.

Comment: I checked on Drupal Answers, and the cross-referenced IP addresses table says I shared my IP address with @Jeff Atwood. The problem is that I have connected to Drupal Answer from my house in Italy, while Jeff Atwood is in California. How can it be possibly true?

Comment: Didn't you get the answer to this the other day?

Comment: @Grace - yes, but only in chat. Someone needs to post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @PopularDemand - I've forgotten what the answer was now :) I do remember that the last comment was to prompt Grace to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right.

The answer is that when a post is migrated by a moderator the post history on the destination site stores the user id of the post owner but the IP address of the moderator doing the migration (don't ask me why - ask the team).

This means that stuff migrated to Web Apps will have the IP address of the SU (say) moderator and *that's* why Diago's IP address appears in the list and my IP address appears against other users.

Comment: This was fixed a while ago, so it shouldn't happen on migrations today anymore (unless you have a recent example?)

Comment: @balpha - no. Just that Popular Demand prompted me to answer given that no one from the team did....

Comment: That's fine, just making sure.

Comment: Whoops, I totally forgot to follow up here when we looked at it / fixed it.  Sorry Chris!

Answer (score 1):

Any chance your OpenID provider is hosting in South Africa, and IP addresses used during log in are also recorded?

(For any moderator who can see my IP addresses: x.x.99.180 is me; x.x.169.19 is used for my OpenID.)

Comment: I don't think so - it looks like each IP address only has been "used" once. Most visits are from my home IP and what I assume is my work IP.